# How to source data from multiple sheets to one sheet based on a specific criteria

Tags: database, excel, vba

I have four excel sheets, One displays the data for this week (Sheet1), second displays the data from last week (sheet 2), third sheet has all the records (Sheet 3) which can be there in any sheet, i.e. sheet 1 or sheet 2 and fourth has the data with which we identify if the data should be sourced from Current Week or last week (Sheet 4, can also be mentioned as scope sheet).

For e.g. if "XXXX" mentioned in third sheet is available in the sheet4, then it will copy all the related records from Sheet 1, else the record should be picked from Sheet 2.

I have tried using vlookup; however, the output is required in Sheet 5 and the problem is that i need to have all number of records already in Sheet 5 for whole data (all records of sheet 3, if a single record is coming three times, i should have three rows in sheet 5 with the same number). I want to make my sheet dynamic and feel it can only be done using a Macro code. Can anyone help me with this.

I think this can be used using Autofilter, but i am not sure how i should put it to use, as i have around 500 records for which i want data and each record have atmost five related records in either Sheet1 or Sheet2.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need to review your data architecture. There is a no-fail, golden rule:

Data input on one sheet.

Reporting on other sheets.

> > I have four excel sheets, One displays the data for this week (Sheet1), second displays the data from last week (sheet 2), third sheet has all the records (Sheet 3)

This is not good data architecture. Rather than create VBA that helps you support bad architecture, I recommend that you re-organise your file to adhere to good practice spreadsheet design.

You don't need to copy data, you just need to show the correct data in your reports. Reports can easily be created from a data input sheet. No need for VLookup. Time frames like "this week" or "last week" can be shown with filters in your report.

Comment: Hi Teylyn, Thanks for your response. Its still a work in progress file which i m preparing. Current week and last week data are pulled from a software and i cant really change those outputs. Plus the scope sheet is provided by a third party. I just have sheet 3 with me, which list all the records. I am looking for a code to extract data from the reports i got from the system and display correct information on the final tab (sheet 5)